# How to display and control the app version in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to control the version of my website in `angular 8`

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Comment: please add some more details.

Comment: I would like to write in the footer section of the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to manage the version in environment.ts then you can inject environment into your app or footer component and set the value of a bound property to the version.  This allows you to have different versions per environment.  Something like.

```
// environment.ts
export const environment {
  production: false,
  version: '1.2.0'
  ...
}
```

```
@Component(...)
export class FooterComponent {
  version: string;
  constructor(environment) {
    this.version = enviroment.version;
  }
}
```